# Export and Import Mongodb from Meteor APP

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, terminal, meteor

How is it possible to Import and export the MongoDB from Meteor APP into .json or .csv file ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mongoexport` utility to export into a .json or .csv file and `mongoimport` to import to your db. Detailed info is found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/

Comment: i have gone through those tips before, while I write the command, there is a msg comes out which is
"connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 0 records"
there isn't any record has been saved to the file.

Comment: @Shams, you may need to specify the database `meteor`

Comment: @Shams, yeah, try this: `mongoexport --host localhost --port 3001 --db meteor --collection collection_name --out collection_name.json`

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to reimport into mongodb, `mongodump` might be a bit better since you won't be losing type information

Try `mongodump`

```
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:3001
```

Here you get BSON, and separate key indexes in json files. Then you can use the dumps to restore your db (if this is your intention):

If you're in the dump directory from above:

```
mongorestore --host 128.199.224.29:27017 --db meteor .
```